# Как сдвинуть ячейки таблицы к правому краю?

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется таблица с примерно такой структурой строк:

```
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5  3начение_6 3начение_7
3начение_1 3начение_2
3начение_1
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5  3начение_6 3начение_7
3начение_1 3начение_2
3начение_1
```

Нужно их сместить к такому виду:

```
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5 3начение_6 3начение_7
                                                       3начение_1 3начение_2
                                                                  3начение_1
                                            3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5 3начение_6 3начение_7
                                                       3начение_1 3начение_2
                                                                  3начение_1
```

Вручную сместить можно, но если строк за тысячу и больше, то на это уйдет  довольно много времени.

Как при помощи макроса реализовать подобный сдвиг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, без проверок и ограничений:

```
Sub OffsetData()
Dim rRng As Range, ArrData()
Dim lClmns As Long, lCnt As Long
Dim bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, p As Long, k As Long
    Set rRng = Application.InputBox("Выделить диапазон данных", "", , Type:=8)
    ArrData = rRng.Value: lClmns = UBound(ArrData, 2)

    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrData) ' по строкам
        k = 0: bFlag = False

        For j = lClmns - 1 To 1 Step -1 ' поиск первого правого значения
            If ArrData(i, j) <> Empty Then ' найдено первое правое значение
                For p = j To 1 Step -1 ' перенос значений
                    ArrData(i, lClmns - k) = ArrData(i, p) ' переносим значение
                    ArrData(i, p) = Empty ' удаляем значение
                    k = k + 1: bFlag = True
                Next p

                If bFlag Then Exit For ' переходим на следующую строку
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    rRng.Value = ArrData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim maxColumn As Integer, valuesColumn As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Нужный Лист")
maxColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' Максимальное кол-во столбцов
For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ' количество столбцов со значениями в текущей строке
    valuesColumn = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Rows(i).Address))
    If valuesColumn < maxColumn Then
        For j = 1 To maxColumn - valuesColumn
            ws.Cells(i, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: С UsedRange аккуратнее. UsedRange.Columns.Count покажет количество столбцов используемого диапазона листа, но не последний заполненный. Если данные расположены начиная с первого столбца, то ничего страшного, работать будет корректно. Еще возможная ошибка: если на листе, кроме нужных данных, есть другие заполненные столбцы.

Comment: @vikttur, наличие слева пустых столбцов никак не повлияет на работу макроса. А про наличие посторонней информации в задании нет ни слова.

Comment: Да я же не с претензией :) Так, узелок на память

Comment: @vikttur, я понял, может мой комментарий выглядит как-то резко, но это не так. Просто ответил без лишних слов на случай, если кому-то пригодится мой способ, но будут сомневаться после Вашего комментария.