# Cдвинуть ячейки таблицы к правому краю

Tags: libre-office

Ранее пользовался MS офисом для сдвига ячеек:

```
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5  3начение_6 3начение_7
3начение_1 3начение_2
3начение_1
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5  3начение_6 3начение_7
3начение_1 3начение_2
3начение_1
```

К такому виду:

```
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5 3начение_6 3начение_7
                                                       3начение_1 3начение_2
                                                                  3начение_1
                                            3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3
3начение_1 3начение_2 3начение_3 3начение_4 3начение_5 3начение_6 3начение_7
                                                       3начение_1 3начение_2
                                                                  3начение_1
```

Для этого использовал соответствующий макрос.

Как можно реализовать подобное в *LibreOffice Calc*?

Нужной русскоязычной информации по созданию макроса не нашел.

Comment: как на `VBA` это реализовано?

Comment: Реализовано [VBA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560430/217235)